# How to Apply FadeIn on Hover with Background img?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fade

I've used this jquery for a couple applications which basically does an img swap with a fading transition. Super simple

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "opacity": "0"
        }, "fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            "opacity": "1"
        }, "fast");
    });

});​
```

with an HTML mark up this

```
<div id="leftBox" class="fadehover inline">
        <img src="images/leftTop.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
        <img src="images/leftBot.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/*fadeHover*/
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
        }

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

I'm wondering if this can be applied to a background image?

I'm trying to do it with in the style tag but not having any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily do it the way you are, but it can be achieved by simultaneously animating the other image. Based on your html, this should do it:

```
$("img.a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
        $("img.b").animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
        $("img.b").animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
    }
);​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/afTtH/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can be possible. You JS code would work fine for that scenario as well. Just need to modify the img.a css class a bit.

```
img.a {
        display: block;
        background: url('your-image') no-repeat bottom left;
        padding: 0 0px 32px 200px;
}​
```

Please note that the padding attribute plays a vital role here and before setting it correctly you should know the height and width of the background image, otherwise image will not be visible fully.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V7wB6/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#home').mouseenter(function(){
$('.home_hover').fadeIn();
});

$('#home').mouseleave(function(){
$('.home_hover').fadeOut();
});
});

<div id="home">
<div class="home_normal">Home</div>
<div class="home_hover">Home</div>
</div>
```

with CSS

```
#home{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    width: 88px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
.home_normal{
    position:absolute;
    height: 25px;
    width: 88px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
.home_hover{
    background-image:url(../images/menuBG-1.0.jpg);
    height: 25px;
    width: 88px;
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
```